# UIWebView not accepting cookies

Tags: javascript, ipad, cookies, uiwebview

I've got an iPad app with a UIWebView in it, and need it to accept cookies via calls from JavaScript. It seems to not accept new cookies, even after explicitly setting the 'cookieAcceptPolicy' of NSHTTPCookieStorage to 'always'.

I saw one other unanswered question on this suggesting the problem might be related to iOS 4.2: http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/81bc91bdbfe7bf7b

Can anyone confirm that UIWebView accepts cookies >= iOS 4.2.1?

Also, here is the javascript that tries to set the cookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Called by:

```
setCookie("ReferrerValue",document.URL,365);
```

I guess if this can't work I'll need a way to do it Objective-C but that is a whole other question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the web page being called via the web view?

If so, then you *should* have the ability to use libraries like [lawnchair](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/quickstart/) or [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) for simple client side persistant storage.

If not and probably a good idea in any case is to take a look at the specific iOS code in [Callback](https://github.com/callback/phonegap) AKA PhoneGap. This problem has been solved, its just a matter of finding where exactly it is. HTH